# Updating JDK 7 to 8: Unable to locate package

Tags: 14.04, java, oracle

I'm attempting to update Java on my Ubuntu 14.04 server from JDK 7 to 8. I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) which says to run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I have run these commands, but on the last one this is the output:

```
root@ns4:~# sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

Can someone help me with this issue? My intention is to update Java (Open JDK) from version 7 to version 8.

Comment: It should work. Are you connected to internet?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I'm connected remotely through SSH.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r 'webupd8team/java' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking to install OpenJDK. The webupd8team PPA installs Oracle Java.

For the record though, I had the same problem installing Oracle Java. Opening a root terminal at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, I renamed `webupd8team-java-precise.list` to `webupd8team-java.list` then ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 4):

For installing openjdk using Radhwane's command list if you face problem with the first command i.e if you get an error like "Please check the ppa name.." just add a -E flag to the command.

`sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa`

and then,

`sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the openjdk instead of the oracle version.
You can find it in the "openjdk-r" repository by addin g it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
```

Then as usual:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and this solved my problem:

My OS version was trusty, in your case just replace the trusty with the proper OS version:

1. /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ it must have webupd8team-ubuntu-java-**trusty**.list file with this content, if not, create the file with the content:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu **trusty** main

2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the support..oracle-java8-installer is no more available
try below:

sudo apt-get install  oracle-java11-installer

It works twice for me